# How to prevent the new iTunes from opening everytime I connect my development device?

Tags: iphone, itunes

Since the last update, there is no option anymore under the Device section to prevent iTunes from annoying me. Is there a tool that will kill iTunes automatically every time it opens? Or is there another way to get rid of this?

Comment: I looked in my iTunes 10.0.1, and in the Device tab there is an option to prevent iOS devices from syncing automatically. That also stops iTunes from opening at all.

Answer (score 2):

There's a checkbox "Open iTunes when this devices is connected" on the Summary tab of the device's site in iTunes.

Comment: This doesn't help when the device doesn't show up in iTunes (my case).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is to go into Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>), open the Processes tab, find 'ituneshelper' and end the process. You should now be able to connect your phone in any mode without iTunes opening automatically.